# What's the meaning of "reuse space"?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I'm reading [this](http://math.mit.edu/~rothvoss/18.304.1PM/Presentations/1-Chandler-18.304lecture1.pdf).

> $\quad \;\;$[image]

What's the meaning of *reuse space* in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you don't create new matrices $D^{(n)}$ but just modify the values in the one matrix. Well, not in one matrix but you have two where one is the previous one ($D^{(n - 1)}$) and the second is the one you compute. When a new $D^{(n)}$ is computed, it becomes $D^{(n - 1)}$ in the next iteration and the previous $D^{(n - 1)}$ (now $D^{(n - 2)}$) becomes a space for the new $D^{(n)}$.